# Delete Single a occurrence of an element in an array in a Mongodb Document using Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I've been trying to Delete a Single occurrence of an element in an array in a Mongodb Document using Pymongo.

For Example I have this document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ec55af811ac5e2e2aafb2b9"),
"username" : "TestUsername",
"tags" : ["gaming", "gaming", "music"]
}
```

What I have tried is using the Pull operation which I implemented as follows:

```
mycol.update_one({"username": "TestUsername"}, {"$pull": {"tags": "gaming" }})
```

Which updates the table as follows:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ec55af811ac5e2e2aafb2b9"),
"username" : "TestUsername",
"tags" : ["music"]
}
```

What I want for the update command to do is delete only one occurrence of the element "gaming" in the array "tags". How do I go about it? I am unable to find a solution using Pymongo in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following working with ChatGPT and this worked:

```
tag_to_delete = "gaming"  # Specify the tag to delete dynamically

mycol.update_one(
    {"username": "TestUsername"},
    [
        {
            "$set": {
                "tags": {
                    "$function": {
                        "body": """
                            function(tags, element) {
                                var index = tags.indexOf(element);
                                if (index !== -1) {
                                    tags.splice(index, 1);
                                }
                                return tags;
                            }
                        """,
                        "args": ["$tags", tag_to_delete],
                        "lang": "js"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```